# CloudFormation - Manual deletion of resource in a stack and update

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Using `template.yaml`, Cloudformation service created stack having  three s3 buckets.

I deleted one s3 resource manually.

Say the stack name is `stack1`

---

On running the same `template.yaml` again(unchanged), with stack name `stack1`, following this [update_procedure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-direct.html)

does  CloudFormation service update the same stack? with that 
missing bucket....it is not updating with missing s3 bucket in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create two stacks with the same name in the same region. If you were to do this in another region it would create the bucket you deleted but fail to create the other buckets, all assuming you named your buckets in the template. If the buckets we not named (so CloudFormation created the names for you) then it will create all three buckets, but the names will not be the same as they were before.

CloudFormation will not update a stack when you tell it to create a stack.

EDIT:
Based on your updated question, it seems you are asking if the bucket will be recreated. The answer to that is no. CloudFormation sees that nothing has changed in what you've asked for, so no action is taken. As a matter of fact you should get an error when updating, saying something along the lines of "no changes".

There are exceptions to the above "no", but for your purposes here I think it's sufficient.

The easiest solution for you is to remove the S3 bucket, that you deleted, from the template, run the update (it will "delete" it even though it's already gone) and then add it back to the template and update it again. That will cause it to be created again.

If you are worried about this sort of thing happening in the future consider using Drift Detection with CloudFormation.

Comment: Am not re-creating a stack, am updating it. Please check the updated query

Comment: How do we include "drift detection" in CFTemplate?

Comment: It's not part of the template, it's an action you can take after it's deployed, either via the CLI, code, or the Console.

Comment: Can we update the stack, based on drift detection status of a resource in that stack?

Comment: Drift detection just does what it's name implies, it detects the drift in the resources created by the stack. It doesn't offer a means of fixing it (at least not yet). The fix is the same as before. In general you probably should lock down users' ability to do things like delete S3 buckets and only allow that to happen via CloudFormation. In cases of emergencies you generally have a different user/role that can be used to do things like that, but using that should trigger alarms.